# Show bijection between groups of homotopy classes

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I have to prove that $[X,S^1]_*$ is in a bijection with $[X,S^1]$, where $[...]_*$ is a pointed homotopy group with a distinguished point $x_o$ in $X$ and $1$ in $S^1$.
We have a hint to use for each $f : X \rightarrow S^1$ another function: $f^{'}$ such that $f^{'}(x) = f(x) * f(x_o)^{-1}$ and for each homotopy: $F : X \times I \rightarrow S^1$ a new homotopy $F^{'}(x,t) = F(x,t) * F(x_o,t)^{-1}$. But I don't know how to prove this bijection. Please, help me.

Comment: To clarify: $X$ is a topological space, $[X,S^1]$ is the group of continuous functions $X \to S^1$ under pointwise multiplication mod homotopy, and $[X,S^1]_*$ is the group of continuous functions sending $x_0 \to 1$ under pointwise multiplication mod pointed homotopy?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more hint: you have an obvious inclusion of sets

$$
i: [X, S^1]_* \longrightarrow [X,S^1] \ .
$$

Haven't you? Ok, so the hint they gave to you says how to construct a map in the opposite direction:

$$
r : [X, S^1] \longrightarrow [X,S^1]_* \ .
$$

Namely,

$$
r([f]) = [f'] \ ,
$$

where [f] denotes the homotopy class of $f$.

I would try to prove that these two maps, $i,r$, are inverses one to another -besides being well-defined on homotopy classes.

For instance, without homotopy classes, it's already clear that $r\circ i = \mathrm{id}$, since, if $g: X \longrightarrow S^1$ preserves base points, then $g(x_0) = 1$. Hence $g'(x) = g(x)*g(x_0)^{-1} = g(x)$.

EDIT. You're right that the proof of $i\circ r = \mathrm{id}$ boils down to show that $f \sim f'$. But, as I said in my comment, the straight line homotopy doesn't work here because it's not contained in $S^1$. The second best idea is to normalize the straight line homotopy. That is, you quocient your $H(x,t)$ by its modulus $\vert H(x,t) \vert$, but in this case this doesn't work either (why?).

Instead, for every $x\in X$, you have to move from $f(x)$ to $f'(x)$ *without* exiting de circumference. How to do it? -Well, rotating from one point to another. Like this, for instance:

$$
F(x,t) = f(x)*e^{-it\theta}  \ .
$$

Here, $\theta$ is the argument of the complex number $f(x_0) \in S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ and

$$
e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta
$$

because of the [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_formula). So:

1. Who is $e^{-i\theta}$?
2. Check that, indeed, this $F$ is the homotopy you were looking for.

Comment: Ok, that is true. But I'm wondering... I've tried to show that $r \circ i = id$. We have a function $h : X \rightarrow S^1$. Then $h^{'} = h(x) * h(x_0)^{-1}.$ Then we have embedding $i(h^{'}(x))$. And how can we know that $i(h^{'}(x)) = h(x)$? We don't know anything about h(x_0)...

Comment: In my comment I meant I've tried to show that $i \circ r = id$.. And this is what is hard for me... Sorry for a mistake above.

Comment: Or maybe... Can we define homotopy $H(x,t) = (1-t)(f(x))+t(f(x)*f(x_0)^{-1})$ and so we have that $id$ and $i \circ r$ are in the same homotopy class? And that would be all?

Comment: Nope. You can't. Though it's a good idea to use the straigh line homotopy as first guess, $H(x,t)$ doesn't need to lie in $S^1$ for all $t$. So, it's not a map $H : X\times I \longrightarrow S^1$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. I already got it! I really appreciate your help.